# How to send mail with attachment on aix node

Tags: python, python-2.7, email, aix

I am trying to write a function that sends a file attached via email.

I have this code that can send email but without an attachment. Does anyone know how I can modify my code to do it?

```
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
msg = MIMEText(open("/tmp/file.txt", "rb"))
msg["From"] = "me@example.com"
msg["To"] = "you@example.com"
msg["Subject"] = "This is the subject.
p = Popen(["/usr/sbin/sendmail", "-t", "-oi"], stdin=PIPE)
p.communicate(msg.as_string())
```

Answer (score 0):

use `MIMEMultipart` for the message

```
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart

msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg['From'] = "me@example.com"
msg['To'] = "you@example.com"
msg['Subject'] = "This is the subject."
```

for attaching text

```
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

msg.attach(MIMEText("""Content"""))
#or
with open('text_file.txt', 'r') as text:
    msg.attach(MIMEText(text.read()))
```

similarly for other attachments (an image for example)

```
from email.mime.image import MIMEImage

with open('image_file.png', 'rb') as img:
    msg.attach(MIMEImage(img.read()))
```

Several examples [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/email-examples.html)

and a list of all [MIME objects](https://docs.python.org/2/library/email.mime.html)